# Keeping a text file in android

Tags: android, file-io

I am new to android and facing issue with file system usages.

I have seen several threads but i am still not able to find the answer which i am looking for my requirement.

I have a original file say **test.xml** which i want to keep **somewhere** in my eclipse project  so that as soon as i install the app it should move my test.xml file into data directory so that i would be able to read it

please refere this link : 
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

I want to save my original file at : "/data/data/com.example.helloWorld/files"

I should be able to get the file handle form the below command

File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);

Please Note i dont want to save my file in asset folder.

Thanks,
Manish Bansal

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use assets as storage for your file initially as that will get compiled with your app, then once the user starts your app you check if your file exists and if not you can save the asset to the internal storage location as specified in the documentation, from there you can use the file as you like in the filesystem.